# Robust two lines/segments intersection point in 2D

Tags: computational-geometry, numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis

Given two line segments the problem is to find an intersection point of corresponding lines (assuming that they are not parallel or coincide).

There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line) which gives us exact formulas, but there are two of them: one that uses `t` ratio and approaches intersection point from first line segment and the other -- uses `u` and the second line segment. How can I select which one to use in my scenario?

For example: my initial implementation which always used `t` failed on

```
first_segment = Segment(start=Point(x=-5, y=0), end=Point(x=72057594037954921, y=0))
second_segment = Segment(start=Point(x=0, y=0), end=Point(x=0, y=3))
```

gives

```
Point(x=5.921189464665284e-16, y=0.0)
```

which is incorrect, but when I switch to use `u` or change order of arguments it gives me correct

```
Point(x=0.0, y=0.0)
```

So my question is: is there robust way to calculate intersection point?

Answer (score 2):

If you choose a formula with parameter $t$ you'll get the $P_x$ value as a result of a number of operations - additions, multiplications and one division:

$$t = \frac{(x_1-x_3)(y_3-y_4)-(y_1-y_3)(x_3-x_4)}{(x_1-x_2)(y_3-y_4)-(y_1-y_2)(x_3-x_4)}$$
$$P_x = x_1 + t(x_2-x_1)$$

The number $x_2=72057594037954921$ contains 17 significant decimal digits - so it *can't be represented exactly* using double-precision floating numbers. Apparently, a small error is introduced during some operation (most probably - the division), and this error is propagated to the result. This is a form of the [Round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).

This bunch of calculations doesn't happen when you choose a formula with parameter $u$, because the numerator there is equal to zero.

**Conclusion**: if you need to work with numbers, containing a big number of significant digits - use floating numbers with bigger precision, or may be - with *arbitrary* precision. An example: [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/).

---

Another option - use rational numbers. For example, *kernels*, based on rational numbers, can be found in the computational geometry library [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/). Developers of this library have invested a lot of efforts to solve this robustness problem - please see [this](https://www.cgal.org/exact.html) page for more information.

If you want to go deeper into this research area, called Exact Geometric Computation (EGC), you can start from this [review](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00344355/file/p.pdf). You'll need a good knowledge of [Linear Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) and [Linear Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations).

Comment: so can I detect whether to use `t` or `u` based on absolute value of $x_2$?

Comment: btw I'm using Python with double precision floating point numbers if it matters

Comment: @AzatIbrakov - if you need to find an intersection of two segments you'll have to calculate *both* $t$ and $u$ and make sure that $0 \le t \le 1$ and $0 \le u \le 1$. Your example shows, that in this case you can get *two* intersection points... which one would you choose? You can't get an exact result from inexact intermediate calculations